# fpdf multi cell control

Tags: fpdf

I am using fpdf to generate a report but one of the field I need to be multicell as the contents can be few lines long. Below is the codes what happens now is that the multicell will be few lines long but the rest of it will be only one standard size and the content after multicell will be on the next line. So how to overcome all this problem

```
$row_height = 5; // set the default             
$column_width = 15;

$number_of_lines = ceil( $pdf->GetStringWidth($eventMessage) / ($column_width - 1) );
$cell_height = 5; 
$height_of_cell = ceil( $number_of_lines * $cell_height ); 
if ( $cell_height > $row_height ) {
 $row_height = $cell_height;
}  

$pdf->Cell( 10, $row_height,$count, 1, 0, 'L', true );
$pdf->Cell( 15, $row_height,$row['latitude'], 1, 0, 'L', true );
$pdf->Cell( 16, $row_height,$row['longitude'], 1, 0, 'L', true );
$pdf->Cell( 25, $row_height,$row['dateTimer'], 1, 0, 'L', true );
$pdf->Cell( 25, $row_height,$row['insertDateTime'], 1, 0, 'L', true );

$pdf->MultiCell( 15, $row_height,$eventMessage, 1, 'J',true);
$pdf->Cell( 15, $row_height,$eventSource, 1, 0, 'L', true );
$pdf->Cell( 15, $row_height,$eventLocation, 1, 0, 'L', true );
$pdf->Cell( 18, $row_height,$row['stat'], 1, 0, 'L', true );
```

Comment: Brother , i have fallen same problem but there is not developer to solve it i think. So we are suffered.

Answer (score 0):

```
class pdf extends FPDF {
  function GetMultiCellHeight($w, $h, $txt, $border=null, $align='J') {
    // Calculate MultiCell with automatic or explicit line breaks height
    // $border is un-used, but I kept it in the parameters to keep the call
    //   to this function consistent with MultiCell()
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s = str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb = strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 && $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep = -1;
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $l = 0;
    $ns = 0;
    $height = 0;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        // Get next character
        $c = $s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            // Explicit line break
            if($this->ws>0)
            {
                $this->ws = 0;
                $this->_out('0 Tw');
            }
            //Increase Height
            $height += $h;
            $i++;
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            $ns = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
        {
            $sep = $i;
            $ls = $l;
            $ns++;
        }
        $l += $cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            // Automatic line break
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
                if($this->ws>0)
                {
                    $this->ws = 0;
                    $this->_out('0 Tw');
                }
                //Increase Height
                $height += $h;
            }
            else
            {
                if($align=='J')
                {
                    $this->ws = ($ns>1) ? ($wmax-$ls)/1000*$this->FontSize/($ns-1) : 0;
                    $this->_out(sprintf('%.3F Tw',$this->ws*$this->k));
                }
                //Increase Height
                $height += $h;
                $i = $sep+1;
            }
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            $ns = 0;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    // Last chunk
    if($this->ws>0)
    {
        $this->ws = 0;
        $this->_out('0 Tw');
    }
    //Increase Height
    $height += $h;

    return $height;
  }
}
```

So

```
$pdf = new pdf();
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->MultiCell(50, 4, 'Bla bla bla');
$pdf->ln(GetMultiCellHeight(50, 4, 'Bla bla bla'));
$pdf->Output();
```